# Really slow Xbox 360 as Windows Media Extender

Tags: windows-vista, media-center-extender, xbox360

When I set up my XBox 360 as a Windows Media Extender although I can see all the media I have on my Windows Vista PC it is excruciatingly slow to move between albums etc

Is there anything I can do to improve this or is it just because of the number of media files I have - about 5GB?

Cheers

Comment: Interested in seeing if someone found a solution, since I have the same issue and could never find a workaround.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By any chance, is your PC on a wireless connection? I have that setup and Media Center gives me exactly the same problem. When I actually get an audio or video file running it streams fine, but choosing menu items is agonizingly slow--it can take 30 seconds or more just to move from one menu item to another. It's a [commonly reported issue](http://www.google.com/search?q=xbox+slow+site%3Athegreenbutton.com).

Microsoft [recommends](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/mediacenter/networking.mspx) connecting the PC directly to the router, but they say that the performance issues occur if *both* devices are wireless, and my 360 is wired directly to the router.

Comment: This is spot on, although like you my 360 is wired and my PC is wireless so doesn't quite match what MS are saying. I prefer to use last.fm now so not a big problem but if it becomes one then wired it will be... cheers

Comment: I'm guessing you're both referring to the Media Center portion of the 360, as this is terribly slow for me as well. Meanwhile, with both my Xbox 360 and PC on wireless, streaming videos and music through the normal dashboard by sharing through Windows Media Player works perfect.

Answer (score 3):

I am really disappointed that Windows 7 MCE is working so badly using XBOX-360 as a Media Centre Extender. Vista MCE, using exactly the same setup, worked well, but I am not keen to roll back.

When it is being slow there is no network traffic going over the wire. Surprisingly when I start streaming a live tv channel then the entire user interface suddenly comes back to life and behaves as expected and performs well.

**Update: Disabling the sounds and animations in the extender settings seems to have solved the problem... for now. Would really like to see the pretty animations though ;-)**

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Tversity](http://tversity.com/download) to manage your media files for you. You install it on your Vista machine and it creates a Streaming Server that streams to your Xbox. I have had no issues at all with it and my media library is far bigger than 5GB.

Comment: If I can't find a fix for this then I'll definitely check it out, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Wireless B or G? If so you'll want to switch to using either a 100MB LAN Cable or Wireless N. The reason is Wireless B and G really aren't fast enough for Media Center Extender to work at an optimal speed.